# I want to use MySQL using reflection, but have had to hard code the MySQL jar file - can I download latest version from Maven?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, maven

I have a general tools jar file which access MySQL.  When I looked at the jar file, I saw it had about 11 Mb comprising MySQL and ProtoBuf, while my own code is about .5 Mb.  The MySQL is only used by a couple of my tools, so I would like to download the MySQL stuff, and use reflection for the MySQL functions.

The reflection code is now working, but the MySQL jar file location and version number has to be hard-coded.  It is also Eclipse-dependent (`.m2`).  What I would like to do is always download the latest version of MySQL, and use that.  I think I can use Maven functions to download the latest version *number*, but I'm not sure where to go from there!  Someone suggested Aether - is that still active?

TIA

Comment: Maven can support dependency ranges, see https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html. Note that this jar is resolved at build time.  I'm not sure it fixes your problem, as it just affects how you build your jar.
One caution worth noting about your approach is that changes in that jar can introduce backwards-compatability-breaking changes.  By trying to use reflection to interact with mysql, you're making compile-time errors into runtime errors.

Comment: @Taylor Good point in your last sentence - however, my system is component-oriented, and I want to avoid having each new piece of software that I support bloat my jar file...  Do you (or anyone else) have any approaches to packaging that I haven't thought of or don't know about?  TIA

Comment: You don't need to build a "fat jar", you can compile and ship only your code, against known dependencies, and manage an application environment that has all required libs on the classpath.  This would allow you to upgrade dependencies independently in said application env.  Essentially, though, you're saving bandwidth and disk space at the expense of the time required to manage the application environment.  Fat jars are popular cause they're easy, and *generally* disk and badnwidth are a small price to pay.  Also, there's a niceness to having atomic artifacts that represent your app.

Comment: Thanks, @Taylor, but when I included the MySQL jar file in my classpath it got included in my own jar file, which means that all future users would see mysql in the jar file, whether they need it or not...  Or is something else pulling in the mysql jar file...?  Sorry to be a bit slow!

Comment: It's entirely dependent on how you're building your jar.  You can specify classpath at runtime and not have it in the jar.  How to exclude it from the jar is dependent on how your building the jar.  Maven, by default does not create a fat jar, but it can be done like this: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/maven/maven-build-fat-jar.html or using various plugins.  If you specify a dependency as `provided` scope https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope it will be excluded, as will any transitives via this dep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a working solution using Curl to acess information from Maven - twice: once to figure out the latest version of mysql-connector-java (the jar file), and one to download it.  It works, but I agree with @Taylor 's point, and will see if I can come up with a non-reflection solution.  I will however close this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just use a snapshot of the latest version. As far as I know, Maven searches for new versions on a daily basis if you use -SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Thanks, but I do know how to find out the latest version - my problem is how to download it from Maven and access its classes and methods...  unless @Taylor or someone else has a better packaging technique - see above.  Thanks!